# SendMessage click (works only if the mouse is over the button)

Tags: c#, winapi, sendmessage, postmessage, deviare

I've done this before, but with this specific button, it doesn't work!

If I click the button **manually it creates a new window** (mini-map):
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvWPb.jpg)

///////
But Programmatically **I can see the animation** on the button as if it gets clicked [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQVDO.gif),

But the window (mini-map) **doesn't show up**.

```CS
            int x = 9, y = 8;
            IntPtr lParam = (IntPtr)((y << 16) | x);
            WinAPIs.PostMessage(button, WinAPIs.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, (IntPtr)0x01, lParam);
            WinAPIs.PostMessage(button, WinAPIs.WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, lParam);
```

The mini-map is created **only if the mouse is over the button** when my code sends the messages.

Here's a 10-sec video on YT: [Video](https://youtu.be/aJJnujtWle4),

**Notice:** In the video, I didn't click the button with the mouse,
**I've just hovered it.**

**UPDATE1:** [Spy++ Messages Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKcuR.jpg)

**UPDATE2:** the game is using GetCursorPos and WindowFromPoint to get the handle of the window under the cursor and compare it with the button's handle, I need to figure out how to hook WindowFromPoint to send the button's handle even if the game is in the background.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218132/discussion-on-question-by-w4po-sendmessage-click-works-only-if-the-mouse-is-ove).

Comment: Okay, So I've reverse-engineered the game and it uses GetCursorPos and WindowFromPoint to check the button handle with the message I send,

So now I need to figure out a way to hook WindowFromPoint to send the button's handle even if it's not on the foreground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the answer,

First of all, I had to reverse-engineer the game,

And I've found that it's using **WindowFromPoint** to get the handle of the window under the current cursor's position **and compare it with the button's handle.**

Meaning the bot will not work while the game is in the background.

So I had to figure out how to **hook the WindowFromPoint call and change the return value**, so I can send the button's handle **even if the game is in the background.**

I used this library to do so: **[Deviare](https://github.com/nektra/Deviare2).**

And here is a [Quickstart](http://whiteboard.nektra.com/deviare-v-2-0/quickstart_v-2-0) of how to use it.

**Here is my code:**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Nektra.Deviare2;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private NktSpyMgr _spyMgr;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _spyMgr = new NktSpyMgr();
        _spyMgr.Initialize();
        _spyMgr.OnFunctionCalled += new DNktSpyMgrEvents_OnFunctionCalledEventHandler(OnFunctionCalled);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Search for the game process
        var processes = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("Conquer");
        int processID = 0;
        if (processes.Length < 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Couldn't find Conquer", "Error");
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            //Found the game
            processID = processes[0].Id;
        }

        //Hook WindowFromPoint with 'flgOnlyPostCall' meaning OnFunctionCalled will be triggered after the api call and before the value returns to the game
        NktHook hook = _spyMgr.CreateHook("user32.dll!WindowFromPoint", (int)(eNktHookFlags.flgRestrictAutoHookToSameExecutable | eNktHookFlags.flgOnlyPostCall));
        hook.Hook(true);
        hook.Attach(processID, true);
        
        //Now send the button click and It works.
        int x = 9, y = 8;
        IntPtr lParam = (IntPtr)((y << 16) | x);
        WinAPIs.PostMessage((IntPtr)0x1D02D0, WinAPIs.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, (IntPtr)0x01, lParam);
        WinAPIs.PostMessage((IntPtr)0x1D02D0, WinAPIs.WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, lParam);
    }

    private static void OnFunctionCalled(NktHook hook, NktProcess process, NktHookCallInfo hookCallInfo)
    {
        INktParam pRes = hookCallInfo.Result();

        //change the return value to whatever you want.. 0x1D02D0 here for example
        pRes.Value = new IntPtr(0x1D02D0);
    }
}
```